Error of array with tabulary
Suddenly I am facing issues with tabulary. Consider this MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{LL}
a & b\\
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}

With TL2024 updated just now with tlmgr update --self --all the error of this MWE is:
 Missing \cr inserted.

But this does not happen with  tabularx, for instance. Someone is experiment the same problem?

The problem is known and there will be a fix on ctan soon. Oh, no that is perhaps something else. Did tabulary really know a X column?

@UlrikeFischer Ouch! It caught me in the worst posible moment!  Very thanks to clarify so fast.  I will delete the question when fixed. No, my fault, In my haste I put the wrong columns!. It must  be LL

If you need a fixed version immediately, you can try the current developer version from https://github.com/davidcarlisle/dpctex/tree/main/tabulary. But AFAIK currently this would not work with old version of array.

@cabohah Old? I have  2024/05/23 v2.6c  in array.sty.

@Fran This is the current array version. So the developer version of tabulary should work. So I would download the raw versions of tabulary.dtx and tabulary.ins to a new folder, do a tex tabulary.ins and copy the resulting tabulary.sty into the document folder. But don't forget to remove it, when a new release will be part of TeX Live.

The version of github worked. Many thanks.

@Fran as Ulrike says, I'm working on that literally at this moment, I should get an update to ctan this evening. If you can test the version there with your real code it's good to know it works (email me if not:-)

v0.11 of tabulary was submitted to ctan today so should appear in tex distributions soon

The recent LaTeX update unfortunately broke tabulary.
A matching update to tabulary is being tested and hopefully should be released today. meanwhile you can use the development version available from
https://github.com/davidcarlisle/dpctex/tree/main/tabulary

¯\(ツ)/¯ Things that happen. Thank you very much for the quick fix and for everything else.
